# Stack overflow in Metaprogramming

Tags: c++11, inheritance, stack-overflow, copy-constructor, template-meta-programming

I am reading the book "Advance Metaprogramming in classic C++"! on page 16 the author has provide an example:

```
struct base
{
    base() {}
    template <typename T>
    base(T x) {}
};
struct derived : base
{
    derived() {}
    derived(const derived& that)
        : base(that) {}
};
void main()
{
    derived d1;
    derived d2 = d1; //stack overflow!! why?! 
}
```

the author says: 
"The assignment d2 = d1 causes a stack overflow. An implicit copy constructor must invoke the copy constructor of the base class, so by 12.8(the C++ standard) above it can
never call the universal constructor. Had the compiler generated a copy constructor for derived, it would have called the base copy constructor (which is implicit). Unfortunately, a copy constructor for derived is given, and it contains an explicit function call, namely base(that). Hence, following the usual overload resolution rules, it matches the universal constructor with T=derived. Since this function takes x by value, it needs to perform a copy of that, and hence the call is recursive."

I really didn't get it ! can some one please explain this more!

many thanks!:)

Answer (score 7):

The main issue lies here:

```
base(T x) {}
```

The Constructor for base takes x (meaning d1) as value, which causes x to be temporarily copied. Copying x will result in calling the original copy constructor of derived again, namely this one:

```
derived(const derived& that)
    : base(that) {}
```

This constructor itself will call the first one (base(T x)) again an so on, ergo you get a stack overflow caused by recursive constructor calling.

Comment: I put breakpoints in the code and this is what actually happens!
when it gets to :
derived d2 = d1; 
then it goes to 
derived(const derived& that): base(that) {}
and then it shows the stack overflow messages! although I have put breakpoints at base(T x) {} but it never stops at base(T x) {}. I don't know why?!

Comment: My best guess would be that your IDE is recognizing the stack overflow at this point, as well as breaking the execution to prevent filling your memory.

Comment: as I am debugging the code the compiler should run the code step by step! when it gets to: base(that)  and you press step-in and there is a break point on the base class you expect the code to stop at the base class constructor! it never happens! a recursion should happen to fill the memory! I cant see the recursion when I debug the code. by the way I am using VS2015 to debug the code.

Comment: Like i already said, either your IDE or more likely the debugger behind it recogizes the recursive caling and prevents you from doing so by force. A good debugger should be able to prevent stuff like this even for debugging issues since this is an essential problem.